# How to measure latency on wireless network, while 4 users are on Webex session?

Tags: wireless-networking, video, ethernet, wireless-access-point

Users are complaining that Webex session [4-5 users] on a wireless network has bad quality. How to measure packet loss and document what causes the bad reception?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use MTR / WinMTR  or equivalent - this will show Min, Max, Avg latencies as well as packet loss for each hop - including the first.

The problem is likekly nothing to do with Webex (whatever that is) - its probably noise on the WIFI network

Answer (score 0):

A great latency measuring tool is [DSLReports' speed test](http://dslreports.com/speedtest).

Although this *could* be a Wi-Fi problem, I think it's much more likely to be [bufferbloat](http://bufferbloat.net). Bufferbloat is caused by routers that make the mistake of thinking that it's bad to ever drop any packets even if it means that buffer queues become huge and bloated and never drain, thus just adding lots of latency to everything you do, and blocking TCP's congestion control algorithm from kicking in.

The solution is to use Smart Queuing algorithms such as fq_codel or PIE, in conjunction with Explicit Congestion Notification (ECN), in the boxes where the buffer queues are building up but never draining. Usually this is the box right before the slowest link, and usually the slowest link is your broadband connection. So this is usually about your broadband modem or internet gateway router, and your ISP's DSLAM or CMTS. Smart Queueing is smart enough to trigger ECN, and, if need be, drop packets instead of adding too much latency, so that TCP congestion control can work.

If you have bufferbloat but you can't put better queuing in the boxes where the queues are building up, consider putting in a router with good queueing in between your broadband modem and the rest of your network, and artificially limiting its bandwidth to make it ever-so-slightly the bottleneck in both directions. This allows it to become the place where the queues *would* have built up, but it's smart enough to trigger ECN and drop packets, so TCP congestion control kicks in before buffer queues can build up anywhere on the network.